# CommonNNClustering not included in scikitlearn_extra

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

My installation of scikit-learn-extra via `conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn-extra` does not include CommonNNClustering. The version is 0.1.0b2.  KMedoids works, tho.

I satisfy the dependencies with Python 3.6.10 and scikit-learn 0.23.2. Nevertheless, after

```
import sklearn_extra
sklearn_extra.cluster.CommonNNClustering()
```

I get the "AttributeError: module 'sklearn_extra.cluster' has no attribute 'CommonNNClustering'."

Comment: can add your code to easily understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the version installed via conda or pip does not include these modules or the scripts `_commonnn.py`. I ran into the same error.

If I install the development version:

```
pip install https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/scikit-learn-extra/archive/master.zip
```

It works:

```
from sklearn_extra.cluster import CommonNNClustering
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[2, 2], [2.1, 2.1], [33.3, 33.3], [34.2, 34.2], [111, 111]])
clustering = CommonNNClustering(eps=3, min_samples=0).fit(X)
clustering.labels_
array([ 0,  0,  1,  1, -1])
```